# How to Find minimum and maximum using `FindMaximum[]` and `FindMinimum[]`

Tags: plotting, mathematical-optimization, fitting

this is the data that i use to plot. [data_damped_osccilation](http://comsics.usm.my/tlyoon/teaching/ZCE111_1516SEM2/data/data_A6Q2.dat)

this is my code so far, however it still give me error

```
datadamped = Import["Datadamped.txt", "Data"]
qqq = ListPlot[datadamped]
i[c_, d_, e_, t_, h_] := c *Exp[(-d*e*t) Sin[(Sqrt[1 - d^2]) e*t + h]]
datadx = NonlinearModelFit[datadamped, i[c, d, t, e, h], {c, d, e, h},
   t]
Show[ListPlot[datadamped], Plot[datadx[t], {t, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}]]
NonLdataFit["BestFitParameters"];
```

[image]

How to find maximum and minimum? 
secondly how can i find first minimum and the vaues of `t` where this occur?
thirdly how to know the exact coordinates of the second maximum at `t=1.0` ?

all help is appreciated. thank you.

Comment: Your fitting model does not seem to reproduce the behavior of your data at least for some values of the parameters. Consider for instance: `Plot[i[1, 0.01, 6, t, 1], {t, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> All]`, which returns this: [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QAZiq.png).

Comment: Do you really need a fit or you just need the maximums/minimums?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
datadamped = 
  Import["http://comsics.usm.my/tlyoon/teaching/ZCE111_1516SEM2/data/\
data_A6Q2.dat", "Data"];

max = datadamped[[#]] &@FindPeaks[datadamped[[All, 2]], 0][[All, 1]]
min = datadamped[[#]] &@FindPeaks[-datadamped[[All, 2]], 0][[All, 1]]
```

This gives you list of maximums and minimums. If you need a fit you probably want to simplify the fitting space and optimize for different fit parameters:

```
g = NonlinearModelFit[datadamped, 
  A Exp[-b x] Sin[c x + h], {A, b, c, h}, x]
Show[ListPlot[{datadamped, max, min}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red, Green}], 
 Plot[g[x], {x, 0, 5}, PlotStyle -> {{Dashed, Orange}}]]
```

[image]

Your data doesn't look real, since the fit was too good to be true :)
For real data you probably want to play with parameters for `FindPeaks`.
If you trust your fit better than your data, you can find peaks from fitted function now:

```
minfit = {x, g[x]} /. 
  Solve[g'[x] == 0 && g''[x] > 0 && x > 0 && x < 5, x]
maxfit = {x, g[x]} /. 
  Solve[g'[x] == 0 && g''[x] < 0 && x > 0 && x < 5, x]
```

And finally you can use `FindMinimum` if you really want to use this function:

```
FindMinimum[g[x], {x, 0}]
```

And it gives the same answer as `minfit[[1]]`

Now you probably want to find out your original parameters set $d,e$

```
params = g["BestFitParameters"]
Solve[-d e == b && Sqrt[1 - d^2] e == c /. params, {d, e}]
```

> `{A -> -0.5, b -> 0.628319, c -> -6.25169, h -> 4.71239}`
>
> `{{d -> 0.1, e -> -6.28319}}`

And $e$ really looks suspiciously close to $2\pi$

Comment: `FindPeaks` is a useful command. thank you. @Blackow

Comment: @Nabil `FindPeaks` is useful, but don't use it blindly. When you have real data, you almost always need to deal with noise. `FindPeaks` can add smoothing to your data, see more [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/85774/cutting-away-points-that-are-not-resonances/85793)